# How to parse integer column to String in CDAP (Datafusion)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

Need your help to understand how **Integer** columns can be **parsed** to **String** Columns in **Data Fusion** using **wrangler** plugin.
Apologies to this naïve question as I am quite new to GCP and I tried googling it but could not find any solution.

Regards,
Vaishali

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Wrangler Plugin supports parsing to limited formats. Integer to String parsing is not supported in the Data Fusion Wrangler plugin according to this [doc](https://github.com/data-integrations/wrangler). You can change the datatype of the data but parsing is not possible for integers to string.